# "Debugging" with bashdb: why do I lose command echo after stepping into a simple script?

Tags: bash, debugging, bashdb

I heard about the *bash debugger* ( [`bashdb`](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/) ) after reading a [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118789/are-there-any-well-known-and-well-used-shell-scripting-ides-for-unx#comment186106_118789) so I thought I should try it out and see if it can help me analyze bash scripts or more generally the execution of commands. There are [facilities](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59511/shell-script-debugging) which can be leveraged independently of any external program but there is the question of convenience and bashdb runs in the shell and can be called directly or with `bash --debugger command` when properly configured.

So I tried something trivial in a script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

{ echo 'abc'; echo 'def'; } | cat
```

Which is just two `echo` commands in a *list* uselessly piped into the `cat` command. Using `bashdb scriptname` I get:

```
(/home/user/bin/scriptname:3):
3:  { echo 'abc'; echo 'def'; } | cat
(/home/user/bin/scriptname:3):
3:  { echo 'abc'; echo 'def'; } | cat
bashdb<0> bashdb<(0)> step
```

So there is a pipe operator and a subshell is created - the parentheses around the 0 are tribute to that. I try to `step` in right away. A newline is output but I don't get back the debugger prompt... until I press enter again. By that point I have lost the output of what I type in the debugger and performance seems highly degraded. Doing `q` and pressing enter, I exit the debugger and now my terminal no longer outputs my commands either. Commands get executed but I need to exit a start a new terminal window to regain any command echo. In some cases, both in the tool and after quitting in bash, not only the commands are no longer echoed but the newline following commands is gone too.

So obviously I have very little experience with that sort of software but this seems to be the desired behavior as I get similar results both on Gentoo and Archbang?? So what happened here and what did I step into?

Comment: I had a similar situation in the context of sending to the background a job without having a controlling terminal with PD-KSH. So somehow in the example here I've triggered a condition where the commands compete for terminal control so many keystrokes are required for each key etc.

Answer (score 1):

What is going on is that the pipe sets output by default is to go to cat, and that includes debugger output. There is `--tty` option to tell the debugger where to send output, but that's not doing what I expect it to. (To see what value to put after `--tty` run `tty`. File this as a [bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/bashdb/bugs/) and I'll look at it when I can.